# Returning duplicate results SQL?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have the following query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS 
    unr.RequestID, 
    unr.UnRead, 
    unr.FilterID, 
    r.GroupID, 
    r.Year, 
    rv.Bounty 
FROM (users_notify_requests as unr, requests_votes as rv) 
    JOIN requests AS r ON r.ID = unr.RequestID
WHERE unr.UserID = 1 ORDER BY unr.RequestID DESC LIMIT 50
```

This should return only 2 rows, as there are only two requests where `unr.UserID = 1`, however it returns 10. 5 versions of the first, and 5 versions of the second, completely identical (respectively). Any idea as to why this might be happening?

EDIT: MySQL version 5.5.29, as requested.

EDIT 2: The `print_r()` dump: http://pastebin.com/BXujnEpx. The result has incorrect bounty for the given IDs, so something is pretty off with the query.

Comment: Something tells me the rows are not "completely identical". If you have two rows with the same ID, but different in any other column, they are considered different and distinct. Even if there are 10 columns with 9 the same, that 10th column makes them distinct.

Comment: You are cross joining requests_votes and users_notify_requests, I bet that is causing them.

Comment: Which MySQL version are you using?

Comment: They are completely identical. [here](http://i.imgur.com/uWp7Ew3.png)  is a screen shot of what it returns. it only started doing this when I added `request_votes as rv` and `rv.Bounty` to the query.

Comment: Perhaps you could show an actual dump of the result. Like add the rows to an array and print_r it. Your query has 6 columns but that formatted output only shows like 4.

Comment: Notice how on each of those "same" rows, `bounty` is different? That makes those rows not distinct and is a result of your cross join.

Comment: Below the other `JOIN` I added `JOIN requests_votes ON rv.RequestID = r.ID` and that seems to have fixed it. Does that make sense?

Comment: Likely. If requests_votes has a corresponding foreign key column that correlates back to users_notify_requests.

Answer (score 2):

You're not joining on rv with any criteria, so every row in that table will be returned: It could be that this is the cause of your extra rows.

You probably need a line such as the following (guessing at column names as I don't have your schema):

```
INNER JOIN request_votes rv ON rv.requestId = r.id
```

Comment: DISTINCT should eliminate that problem if they're truly identical.

Comment: See the screenshot above. They are truly identical. Each record only exists **once** in the database.

Comment: Yes, but it's unlikely that every row in the table is the same - request_votes is not joined properly, so it's likely that rows that are not relevant to the result set are being returned: Every distinct value in rv.bounty will cause extra rows to be returned. EDIT: My reply was to Joachim, I'll take a look at the screenshot now.

Comment: How do I fix that then?

Answer (score 0):

you are joining two tables based on cartesian product or cross join .

```
FROM (users_notify_requests as unr, requests_votes as rv)
```

And then you are using a inner join.

```
JOIN requests AS r ON r.ID = unr.RequestID
```

To solve the problem you should use inner join in both cases.

Cartesian join is when you join every row of one table to every row of another table. if 1st table contain x rows and y rows in 2nd one the result set will be x*y rows.

```
SELECT DISTINCT
SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS 
    unr.RequestID, 
    unr.UnRead, 
    unr.FilterID, 
    r.GroupID, 
    r.Year, 
    rv.Bounty 
FROM users_notify_requests as unr
    JOIN requests_votes as rv ON rv.RequestID = unr.RequestID
    JOIN requests AS r ON r.ID = unr.RequestID
WHERE unr.UserID = 1 ORDER BY unr.RequestID DESC LIMIT 50
```

Comment: Tried `INNER JOIN`, no luck.

Comment: Yeah, I actually got it right before you posted that. Thanks a ton!